# SVG responsive and introspective component for Svelte

Tags: svg, responsive, svelte

I'm trying to display a SVG component for Svelte, which knows about its viewBox and dimensions, in a responsive way.

So, with this markup:

```
# src/components/Viz.svelte
<svg class="viz"
    viewBox={ ... }
    width={ ... }
    height={ ... }>
    
    <text x="0" y="-10"> { width } * { heigth }</text>
    <text x="0" y="10">  { viewBox }</text>
</svg>
```

Of course the App.svelte has to adapt and fit the whole viewport heght, and contains additional markup:

```
# src/App.svelte
<script>
    $: console.log({ innerWidth, innerHeight })
</script>
<svelte:window
    bind:innerWidth
    bind:innerHeight
/>
<!-- main fits page at 100% height... -->
<main>
    <header> ... </header>
    <article> <Viz /> </article>
    <footer> ... </footer>
</main>
```

The problem are:

- values in console.log lend to be undefined at startup at $-cycle 0, and then have a defined value;
- that causes a flashing/blinking effect on the SVG canvas at startup
- and the worst: texts don't appear at all inside SVG, and Mozilla Tools doesn't "see" and mark them when inspecting the page

How to fix that ?
Should I deal with onMount Svelte handler, or stores?

Comment: Don't do it the 'Svelte' way, which will always produce problems 1 and 2 (unless you add even more Svelte code to hide everyting, then make it appear); instead create the whole SVG string in memory, inject that into the DOM. Native JavaScript ain't that bad.

Comment: thanks @Danny ! I keep yout suggest in mind

I also noticed an error in xmlns declaration (argh)  Fixing it remove the problem of texts... 

For Svelte, I keep trying, since I plan making highly reactive SVG layout with touch events and animations. I try to fix the blink problem using some kind of hiding mechanism with $: viewBox=[-width/2, -height/2, width, height].join(' ') inside JS part and {#if viewBox} inside markup  of my component + probably a transition fade in effet

Comment: Been there, done that. I did a [Svelte ChessBoard](https://svelte.dev/repl/382ed83cd7954f60882bd03b04e49714) then ditched Svelte because native JavaScript gave me: A) the power to touch any DOM elements directly B) always gave me the same JavaScript code in the Browser I could touch and override at will. The Svelte Compiler is like mixing your Lego bricks with super-glue.